# Examples of continua that are contractible but are not locally connected at any point

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, examples-counterexamples, continuum-theory

A continuum is a compact, connected, metrizable space.

What are examples of continua that are contractible but nowhere locally connected, meaning that no point has a neighbourhood basis consisting of connected sets?

The following is an example of a contractible nowhere locally connected metrizable space, but I'm not aware of any compact examples (every segment on the "main line" has segments sticking out on a dense set).

[image: the infinite infinite comb]

Answer (score 2):

The question was [reposted and answered on MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/419732/examples-of-continua-that-are-contractible-but-are-not-locally-connected-at-any/420069#420069). Turns out that there are contractible continua that are nowhere locally connected!